# Foreign key on a Foreign key - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm creating a database for a project in which I need to declare a foreign key on another foreign key for the sake of a checking constraint.

I have a `Person` table and a `Groups` table, both of these contain a `DepartmentID`. Whenever I insert a new task in the `Task` table, I want to check that the `Groups.DepartmentID` matches the `Person.DepartmentID`.

The idea is that a task is linked to a person and has 2 types, a grouptype which defines if its database work, financial work etc and a tasktype which defines if its maintenance, training etc. When a person tries to add a task with a groupType that is not for his/her department it should fail.

I tried adding these attributes to the `Task` table as a foreign key, however declaring a foreign key on a non-unique or non-primary key isn't accepted in Microsoft SQL Server (the `DepartmentID` in the `Person` and `Group` tables cannot be unique!).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE Department 
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(50),
    UNIQUE ("Name")
)

CREATE TABLE Groups
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    GroupType varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Description varchar(255) DEFAULT ('-'),
    DepartmentID int 
        FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Department(ID),
)

CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(50),
    DepartmentID int 
         FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Department(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE TaskType
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    TaskType varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Description varchar(255) DEFAULT ('-'), 
)

CREATE TABLE Task
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    TimeFrame decimal(4,2),
    Yearcount int,
    GroupType varchar(50),
    TaskType varchar(50), 
    WeekNr int,
    ExceptionDetail varchar(255) DEFAULT ('-'),
    PersonID int
)
```

These are the FK attributes in the task table that are not accepted:

```
GDID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Groups(DepartmentID),
PDID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(DepartmentID),
CHECK (GDID = PDID),    

UNIQUE ("TaskType", "GroupType", "WeekNr", "Yearcount"),
FOREIGN KEY (TaskType) REFERENCES TaskType(TaskType),
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (GroupType) REFERENCES Groups(GroupType)
```

Comment: To make a `ForeignKey`, Sir, you need Primary/Unique Key in other table. Why do you want to try this way? `Foreignkey data should be uniquely available in primary table`

Comment: which foreign key is rejected by sql? please post the failing statement.

Comment: These: GDID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Groups(DepartmentID),
PDID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(DepartmentID),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add wider "super keys" to these tables that include the primary key *and* additional columns<sup>1</sup>, then declare the foreign keys using them. Whether you also remove the superfluous smaller foreign keys is a matter of taste:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups(
ID int IDENTITY,
GroupType varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
Description varchar(255) DEFAULT ('-'),
DepartmentID int FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Department(ID),
constraint Group_Dep_XRef UNIQUE (GroupType,DepartmentID)
)

CREATE TABLE Person(
ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Name varchar(50),
DepartmentID int FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Department(ID),
constraint Person_Dept_XRef UNIQUE (ID,DepartmentID)
)

CREATE TABLE Task(
ID int IDENTITY,
TimeFrame decimal(4,2),
Yearcount int,
GroupType varchar(50),
TaskType varchar(50), 
WeekNr int,
ExceptionDetail varchar(255) DEFAULT ('-'),
PersonID int,
DepartmentID int,
constraint FK_Group_Dept_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupType,DepartmentID)
        references Group (GroupType,DepartmentID),
constraint FK_Person_Dept_XRef FOREIGN KEY (PersonID,DepartmentID)
        references Person (ID,DepartmentID),
UNIQUE ("TaskType", "GroupType", "WeekNr", "Yearcount"),
FOREIGN KEY (TaskType) REFERENCES TaskType(TaskType),
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(ID), --Redundant now
FOREIGN KEY (GroupType) REFERENCES Groups(GroupType) --Also redundant
)
```

(I also consolidated `GDID` and `PDID` into `DepartmentID` - if they're always meant to be equal, why store that twice and then have to have another constraint to assert their equality?)

---

<sup>1</sup>If a primary key (or unique key) is sufficient to uniquely identify each row then any wider key which includes the key columns *and* additional columns must also be sufficient to uniquely identify each row.